# How to determine the type of delim used in a txt file?

Tags: r, delimiter, txt, readr

Here is my sample data: https://github.com/Patricklv/Txt-file

I tried to load the data using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_delim("<PATH>\\pgc.cross.SCZ17.2013-05.txt", delim = " ")
head(data)
```

This returns the following results:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  snpid    hg18chr bp    a1    a2    or    se    pval  info  ngt   CEUaf
  <chr>    <lgl>   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 "rs3131… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
2 "rs3131… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
3 "rs3131… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 "rs1048… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
5 "rs1256… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
6 "rs4040… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# … with 1 more variable: ...12 <lgl>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

I also tried:

```
data <- read_delim("<PATH>\\pgc.cross.SCZ17.2013-05.txt", delim = "\t")
head(data)
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  `snpid hg18chr bp a1 a2 or se pval info ngt CEUaf `                   
  <chr>                                                                 
1 "rs3131972\t1\t742584\tA\tG\t1\t0.0966\t0.9991\t0.702\t0\t0.16055"    
2 "rs3131969\t1\t744045\tA\tG\t1\t0.0925\t0.9974\t0.938\t0\t0.133028"   
3 "rs3131967\t1\t744197\tT\tC\t1.001\t0.0991\t0.9928\t0.866\t0\t."      
4 "rs1048488\t1\t750775\tT\tC\t0.9999\t0.0966\t0.9991\t0.702\t0\t0.8364…
5 "rs12562034\t1\t758311\tA\tG\t1.025\t0.0843\t0.7716\t0.988\t0\t0.0925…
6 "rs4040617\t1\t769185\tA\tG\t0.9993\t0.092\t0.994\t0.979\t0\t0.87156"
```

However, when I open the file using Sublime Text, here is what I see:
[image]

I want to know how should I import this txt file so that it will appear as it shows in Sublime Text

Comment: You could try `read_table()`, which ought to work for any whitespace separator, as long as none of the values contain internal whitespace.

Comment: Also, if memory serves `read_delim()` may auto-detect the right separator if you don’t specify `delim` at all.

Comment: I tried dropping `delim = ` at all and was returned `Error: Could not guess the delimiter.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `read.table`.  No packages are used.

```
u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Patricklv/Txt-file/main/pgc.cross.SCZ17.2013-05.txt"
dat <- read.table(u, header = TRUE, na.strings = ".")

str(dat)
```

giving

```
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ snpid  : chr  "rs3131972" "rs3131969" "rs3131967" "rs1048488" ...
 $ hg18chr: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ bp     : int  742584 744045 744197 750775 758311 769185 828418 836671 843817 844113 ...
 $ a1     : chr  "A" "A" "T" "T" ...
 $ a2     : chr  "G" "G" "C" "C" ...
 $ or     : num  1 1 1 1 1.02 ...
 $ se     : num  0.0966 0.0925 0.0991 0.0966 0.0843 ...
 $ pval   : num  0.999 0.997 0.993 0.999 0.772 ...
 $ info   : num  0.702 0.938 0.866 0.702 0.988 0.979 0.439 1.02 0.383 0.251 ...
 $ ngt    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CEUaf  : num  0.1605 0.133 NA 0.8364 0.0926 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Following your idea, I also tried `dat <- read_delim("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\pgc.cross.SCZ17.2013-05.txt", delim = " ",  na = ".")` by specifying "." as na. However, this did not work either. Your approach worked well but I am also curious about how this could be done through read_delim.

Comment: THe problem is that the header has a different delimiter than the data.  `read.table` can handle that in this case but it seems that `read_delim` cannot.  It would be possible to do this: `dat2 <- read_delim(u, skip = 1, na = ".", col_names = names(read_delim(u, delim = " ", n_max = 0)))`

Comment: The code really works. But I may wish to ask how did your determine the type of delimiter for the header and data. I now know that the header is space delimited and the data is tab delimited. But when running into problems, it is essential to be able to determine the type of delimiter. THANK YOU!

Comment: It is apparent from the output shown in the question. A space represents itself and a backslash t represents a tab.  That said I would just use `read.table` and avoid all these unnecessary complications.